# Cannot Find Resources when using .htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Originally, I have a page with the URL https://schoolname.edu.hk/path/?parameter=value

Now, I want to obtain the below scenario:
when user access the URL https://schoolname.edu.hk/?parameter=value , I want to redirect to the above URL

I tried to set up .htaccess like this:

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} schoolname.edu.hk [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://schoolname.edu.hk/path/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

The URL is changed successfully. However, resources such as CSS and Image files all failed to load.

Comment: Before i set up the .htaccess, the URL https://schoolname.edu.hk/path/?parameter=value works fine

Answer (score 0):

Exclude static content from being rewritten, add the following condition before rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
```